# Array filter is not working inside array of array object?

Tags: javascript

Trying to get an object whose source value is Kitchen and whose invoice files length equal to zero.

I'm using the filter method but it's not returning any value .im not sure why filter method not returns any value .

could someone help here to move forward

Thanks in advance

```js
var data = [{
            "data_id": "1",
            "name": "abc",
            "source":"Hall",
            "sqft": "1100",
            "invoiceItems":[
                    {
                    "inv_id": "1",
                    "price": "925",
                    "Files":[
                        {
                        "filename": "a",
                        "filepath":"zxc"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                    "inv_id": "2",
                    "price": "925",
                    "source":"tymetrix",
                    "Files":[]
                    }
                    ]
        }, {
            "data_id": "2",
            "name": "def",
            "source":"Kitchen",
            "sqft": "1200",
            "invoiceItems":[{
                    "inv_id": "10",
                    "price": "925",
                    "Files":[]
                    },
                    {
                    "inv_id": "11",
                    "price": "925",
                    "Files":[
                        {
                        "filename": "a",
                        "filepath":"zxc"
                        }]
                    }]
        }
          
    ];
    
    //console.log(data)
    var result = data.filter(function (el) {
            if(el.source == "Kitchen"){
                console.log(el.invoiceItems)
                  el.invoiceItems.filter(function(inv){
                       console.log(inv.Files);
                       if(inv.Files.length == 0)
                       {
                       return true;
                       }
                      
                  });
            }
            
        });
        console.log("result",result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning anything from the outer `filter`

also you can simplify your logic in this way

```js
var data = [{
    "data_id": "1",
    "name": "abc",
    "source": "Hall",
    "sqft": "1100",
    "invoiceItems": [{
        "inv_id": "1",
        "price": "925",
        "Files": [{
          "filename": "a",
          "filepath": "zxc"
        }]
      },
      {
        "inv_id": "2",
        "price": "925",
        "source": "tymetrix",
        "Files": []
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "data_id": "2",
    "name": "def",
    "source": "Kitchen",
    "sqft": "1200",
    "invoiceItems": [{
        "inv_id": "10",
        "price": "925",
        "Files": []
      },
      {
        "inv_id": "11",
        "price": "925",
        "Files": [{
          "filename": "a",
          "filepath": "zxc"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }

];

//console.log(data)
var result = data.filter((el) => 
 el.source === "Kitchen" && el.invoiceItems.some(inv => inv.Files.length == 0)
 );
console.log("result", result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see in your code is return key is missing

```
 //console.log(data)
    var result = data.filter(function (el) {
            if(el.source == "Kitchen"){
                console.log(el.invoiceItems)
               return  el.invoiceItems.filter(function(inv){ // here
                       console.log(inv.Files);
                       if(inv.Files.length == 0)
                       {
                       return true;
                       }
                      
                  });
            }
            
        });
        console.log("result",result)
```